# <media:content> missing in RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am setting up a Newsletter and it requires **< media:content>** from my RSS feed to pull images. My Wordpress Blog RSS dos not contain any  at all and I am wondering how I can change my Feed? https://www.chrisontour84.de/feed

Instead I am getting some kind of encoded content:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><a href="https://www.chrisontour84.de/2018/01/03/ice-caves-in-iceland-german-trip-report/"><img data-attachment-id="10784" data-permalink="https://www.chrisontour84.de/news/ice-caves-in-iceland-german-trip-report/attachment/guest_ice_cave/" data-orig-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?fit=782%2C163&amp;ssl=1" data-orig-size="782,163" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="#guest_ice_cave" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?fit=300%2C63&amp;ssl=1" data-large-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?fit=645%2C134&amp;ssl=1" class="alignleft wp-image-10784 size-full" style="border: 1px solid #000000;" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?resize=645%2C134" alt="" width="645" height="134" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?w=782&amp;ssl=1 782w, https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?resize=300%2C63&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/www.chrisontour84.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guest_ice_cave.jpg?resize=600%2C125&amp;ssl=1 600w" sizes="(max-width: 645px) 100vw, 645px" data-recalc-dims="1" /></a></p>
```

Things I have checked are:

- disabling all Wordpress PlugIns
- resetting to Standard Theme
- resetting plugins folder via FTP

All of which did not bring the media:content back. Any other ideas?

Hopefully someone can help me and I can grab my Images into the Newsletter.

Thanks!
Chris

EDIT: No one at all is able to help here? :(

Comment: Things I have checked are:

- disabling all Wordpress PlugIns
- resetting to Standard Theme
- resetting plugins folder via FTP

All of which did not bring the media:content back. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `media:content` element is part of the MediaRSS specification, which enhances the support for multimedia elements in RSS items.

The first thing I'd try to add `media:content` to your blog is the [Hetjens MediaRSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hetjens-mediarss/) plugin. This requires that you can add plugins to your blog, of course.

If you identify the newsletter software or site that requires `media:content` I can check to see whether this solution suits your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the plugin but the media:content is still missing sadly :( any other ideas?